# AngularJS lazy rendering (not lazy loading views)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a lot (3000+) of items I want to render (in a `ng-repeat`) in a div with a fixed height and `overflow: auto`, so I'd get `N` visible items and a scrollbar for the rest of them.

I'm guessing doing a simple `ng-repeat` with so many items will probably take a lot of time. Is there a way I can make AngularJS render only those visible `N` items?

Edit:

An infinite scroll is not what I want. I want the user to be able to scroll to any point of the list, so I literally want a text editor-like behavior. Said with other words: I'd like the scroll to contain the "height" of all the items, but place in the DOM just a few ones.

Comment: you can simple slice array for ng-repeat with count that you needed

Comment: @Grundy And what is `what I need`? How am I going to have a scrollbar if I'm only `ng-repeat`-ing N elements instead of all of them? I mean... I'm not really sure you understand exactly what I'm asking. Can you re-read my question?

Comment: for example: you have collection with 3000 items, first you do something like: `arrForShow=items.slice(0,20)` and then on scroll just add items to `arrForShow` and do `ng-repeat` for this

Comment: @Grundy on scroll on what? What would I scroll?

Comment: conteiner where you place your div.

Comment: @Grundy In order for me to do a scroll, the container would need to contain elements. If I place the elements there, there would be no need to make the entire slicing thing. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92665/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexandernst).

Answer (score 2):

> This answer provides an approach for lazy-rendering only items currently in-view, as defined by the edit to the original question. *I want the user to be able to scroll to any point of the list, so I literally want a text editor-like behavior. Said with other words: I'd like the scroll to contain the "height" of all the items, but place in the DOM just a few ones.*

Install the [`angular-inview`](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview) plugin before trying this.

In order to get your scrollheight you'd need something holding the space for your array items. So I'd start with an array of 3000 simple items (or combine with infinite scroll to whatever extent you want.)

```
var $app = angular.module('app', ['infinite-scroll']);

$app.controller('listingController', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.listOfItems = new Array($window._bootstrappedData.length);
  $scope.loadItem = function($index,$inview) {
    if($inview) {
      $scope.listOfItems[$index] = $window._bootstrappedData[$index];
    }
  }
});
```

Since we're talking about flexible heights, I would create a placeholder for what your content looks like pre-render.

```
<div ng-controller="listingController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in listOfItems track by $index" in-view="loadItem($index,$inview)" style="min-height:100px"><div ng-if="item">{{item.name}}</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using `ng-if` will prevent rendering logic from being run unnecessarily. When you scroll an item into view, it'll automatically display. If you want to wait a second to see if the user is still scrolling you could set a timeout in the `loadItem` method that cancels if the same index gets pushed out of view within a reasonable time period.

> **Note:** If you truly wanted to avoid putting anything in the DOM, you could set your scrollable area to a specific multiple of your "placeholder" height. Then you could create a directive that uses that height to determine the indexes of the items that should be displayed. As soon as you display new items, you'd need to add their heights to the total and make sure you position them at the right spot and make sure your directive knows how to interpret those heights into evaluating the next set of displayed elements. But I think that's way too radical and unnecessary.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the entire thing extremely slow as `inview` would need to evaluate if each of the 3000 elements is visible?

Comment: I haven't checked the performance on this solution. But we're talking about a compromise, since I'm assuming your rendering logic is pretty heavy based on your question. The inview directive does a pretty basic math check and isn't doing any rendering. The sets are limited to what you have in view, so my guess is that even with 3000 comparisons, you're not going to be seeing a radical effect. You'd have to run some metrics to see which is faster at the end of the day.

Comment: You could also fork the directive and add some limitations so that it checks progressively. If you're displaying your elements in a linear fashion, you would know based off the last scroll position and scroll direction what elements you can ignore, in this case you would only need to iterate in one direction until you found an item out of view and could stop.

Answer (score 1):

> Expanding on Grundy's point of using `.slice()`.

I use [`ngInfiniteScroll`](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll) when I need to lazy-render/lazy-load data.

I would keep those 3000 records *out* of your scope to prevent weighing down your digest performance unnecessarily and then append them to your scope data as you need them. Here's an example.

```
var $app = angular.module('app', ['infinite-scroll']);

$app.controller('listingController', function($scope, $window) {

  /*
   * Outside of this controller you should bootstrap your data to a non-digested array.
   * If you're loading the data via Ajax, save your data similarly.
   * For example:
   * <script>
   *   window._bootstrappedData = [{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:2,name:'bar'},...];
   * </script>
   */
  var currentPage, pageLength;
  $scope.listOfItems = [];
  currentPage = 0;
  pageLength = 100;
  $scope.nextPage = function() {
    // make sure we don't keep trying to slice data that doesn't exist.
    if (currentPage * pageLength >= $window._bootstrappedData.length) {
      return false;
    }

    // append the next data set to your array
    $scope.listOfItems.push($window._bootstrappedData.slice(currentPage * pageLength, (currentPage + 1) * pageLength));
    currentPage++;
  };

  /*
   * Kickstart this data with our first page.
   */
  return $scope.nextPage();
});
```

And your template:

```
<div ng-controller="listingController" infinite-scroll="nextPage()" infinite-scroll-distance="3">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in listOfItems">{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @alexandernst, very intriguing. Are your items a fixed height?

Comment: No, they could have different height.

Comment: Then what you're looking for is impossible (there's no way to determine the appropriate total height without actually rendering the items).

Comment: @DanielBeck agreed. Although placeholders could be rendered. Which is as close to the original intention as I think we can get.

Comment: @DanielBeck also check out my second answer and tell me what you think.

Comment: Does this solution remove items from the DOM as soon as you scroll and they get hidden?